# JavaScript dispatchEvent Not Dispatching

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with getting `dispatchEvent` to work. I'm trying to remove my dependency on jQuery, and have been making my own little extensions to the native API, but I can't get my version of `trigger` to work using `dispatchEvent`.

After console logging everything, I know that the `eventType` is being passed in, the `event` object is being created, and `this` refers to the correct target element. Here's the code I've got, I'd appreciate any help.

```
if (!EventTarget.prototype.trigger) {
    function triggerFunction(
        eventType) {
        const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    EventTarget.prototype.trigger = triggerFunction;
}
```

**Edit**

Here's the rest of the code. There's really nothing much because I was mostly focusing on building up my extensions.

```
if (!EventTarget.prototype.on) {
    function onFunction(
        eventType,
        targetElement,
        listener) {
        if (targetElement) {
            this.addEventListener(eventType, function (
                event) {
                const target = event.target;

                if (target
                    && target.nodeName !== targetElement) {
                    return;
                }

                listener.call(target, event);
            }, false);

            return this;
        }

        this.addEventListener(eventType, listener, false);

        return this;
    }

    EventTarget.prototype.on = onFunction;
}

const _pointerTap = "click";

const photosFunction = () => {
    const $buttonPhotosUpload = document.getElementById("button-photos-upload"),
        $fieldPhotosUpload = document.getElementById("field-photos-upload");

    const onButtonPhotosUploadTap = () => $fieldPhotosUpload.trigger(_pointerTap);

    $buttonPhotosUpload.on(_pointerTap, null, onButtonPhotosUploadTap);
};

document.getElementById("photos") && photosFunction();
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="photos">
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="button-photos-upload">{UPLOAD}</button>
        <input type="file" id="field-photos-upload" accept="image/*" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically when the button is pressed, I want to trigger the click event of the input:file so I can hide it visually with CSS. In my jQuery version this works just fine.

Comment: Works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/gftey7qs/ If you're still experiencing it, can you edit your question to show what other code you're using (such as an attached event listener that isn't firing as desired), so we have a [MCVE] to debug?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, there wasn't much since I was just starting out on this.

Comment: I've added the `on` function, `_pointerTap` was there, probably didn't select it when copy/pasting. I've updated the fiddle, and it behaves the same ways as my project, that is it's not triggering the click. https://jsfiddle.net/n2jbskh8/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that browsers don't only look at the `type` property of your Event, they also require it to inherits from the correct Event sub-class.

In this case, the one sub-class of Event they want is a MouseEvent, so instead of `dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));`, you'd have to do `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))`.

(MCVE borrowed from @CertainPerformance answer).

```js
function triggerMouseFunction(eventType) {
  // here event must be MouseEvent for it to work on <input>
  const event = new MouseEvent(eventType, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
if (!EventTarget.prototype.triggerMouse) {
  EventTarget.prototype.triggerMouse = triggerMouseFunction;
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.triggerMouse('click'); // Works
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">{UPLOAD}</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

But if all you want is really to trigger a click event, then by all means just use [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

No need for any lib, nor for modifying the prototype of EventTarget, which is a real bad idea.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.click(); // Works
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">{UPLOAD}</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I added a `getEvent` function to switch on the `eventType` and return the correct object. I do need it to handle more than the click event though because eventually I want to remove my dependency on jQuery for this project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much more minimal MCVE:

```js
function triggerFunction(eventType) {
  const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
if (!EventTarget.prototype.trigger) {
  EventTarget.prototype.trigger = triggerFunction;
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // input.click(); // Works
  // input.trigger('click'); // Doesn't work
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">{UPLOAD}</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

The problem is that the dispatched event doesn't trigger the (*browser's built-in*) function that opens the input dialog. The dispatched event *does* trigger other normal listeners.

I'm doubtful that there's any way to do it without calling the built-in `click` function that invokes the browser's native code that allows the dialog box to come up. One possibility would be to check if the `eventType` is `click` and if the `EventTarget` is an `HTMLElement`. It seems like sidestepping the issue, but I don't think there's another way when the objective requires invoking the browser's *native code* for the dialog.

```js
function triggerFunction(eventType) {
  if (this instanceof HTMLInputElement && eventType === 'click') {
    return HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(this);
  }
  const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
if (!EventTarget.prototype.trigger) {
  EventTarget.prototype.trigger = triggerFunction;
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.trigger('click'); // Works
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">{UPLOAD}</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

A similar pattern will be necessary when invoking any method that requires native code to run (like `console.log` or `XMLHttpRequest` if `fetch` isn't available, or `setTimeout` - some things just can't be emulated using your own Javascript, and require invoking some native code of the browser).

Also note that it looks like you're only trying to add custom methods to *HTML elements*, in which case it might be good to assign `trigger` to `HTMLElement.prototype` rather than `EventTarget.prototype`:

```js
function triggerFunction(eventType) {
  if (this instanceof HTMLInputElement && eventType === 'click') {
    return HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(this);
  }
  const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
if (!HTMLElement.prototype.trigger) {
  HTMLElement.prototype.trigger = triggerFunction;
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.trigger('click'); // Works
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">{UPLOAD}</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually dispatchEvent(MouseEvent)  would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kaiido, I now have it working again. I added a `getEvent` function to switch on the `eventType` and return the correct Event object. The updated code is like so:

```
function getEvent(
    eventType): Event {
    switch (eventType) {
        case "keydown":
        case "keypress":
        case "keyup":
            return new KeyboardEvent(eventType);
        case "click":
        case "dblclick":
        case "mouseup":
        case "mousedown":
            return new MouseEvent(eventType);
        default:
            return new CustomEvent(eventType);
    }
}

function triggerFunction(
    eventType) {
    const event = getEvent(eventType);

    event.bubbles = true;
    event.cancelable = true;

    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

if (!EventTarget.prototype.trigger) {
    EventTarget.prototype.trigger = triggerFunction;
}
```